# Make compulsory form on ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been trying different ways to make the campaign field compulsory but I can't seem to make it work... 
How do I make the field required and show an error when an empty field is submitted?

I am working on ReactJS App this is what my code looks like,

```js
const SMALL_SIZE = 900;
export default class SponsorDashboard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      url: '',
      credits: null,
      campaign: '',
    }
  }


  generateTestLink = () => {
    let accessToken = localStorage.getItem('Token');
    axios.post(`${config.url}`, 
      { credits: this.state.credits, 
       campaign: this.state.campaign },
      { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}` } }
    ).then(res => {
      clipboard.writeText(`${config.url}`)
      .then(() => {this.copyTestUrl()});
      this.setState({ testUrl: `${config.url}`, credits: null });
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  };
```

This is how my form looks like

```js
  <div className="form-group">
      <label className="pl-0">Campaign:</label>
      <input required className="form-control" value={this.state.campaign} name="Campaign" onChange={(e) => this.setState({campaign : e.target.value})} />
    </div>
       </Col>
        <Col xl={9} xs={12} pb={3}>
          <div className="form-group">
          <label className="pl-0">Generate:</label>
            value={this.state.credits}
            onChange={e => this.setState({ credits : parseInt(e.target.value)})}
          />
        </Col>
        <Col md='auto' xs={12}>
          <Button className="mt-2" size="md" color="primary" onClick={this.generateTestLink}>
            <span className="responsive">Generate</span>
          </Button>
```

Comment: Could you add the code for handleSubmit please?

Comment: Well `<form>` natively has this functionality to prevent the `submit` event from happening if a `required` field is not filled out. 1) wrap the form in an actual `<form>` 2) change the button from type `button` to type `submit` 3) add submit event handler onto the `<form>` element. Submit will not execute if a required field is empty and the browser will show an error message without any additional work. make sure to `preventDefault()` on the event in the handler.

Comment: @webdevdani Hello thank you! please ignore the handleSubmit, I'm not calling it in this form.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Okay, I am still trying to figure out how i'm going to this thank you for the pointers I will try it.

Comment: 1) wrap this in a `<form>` 2) create a handler function and attach it to the `<form>` with `preventDefault()` on the passed `event` 3) update the current button to be `type="submit"` and remove the click handler from that button 4) profit

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Thank you very much! I got it to work! Brilliant!